# vb.net adding a reference

Tags: vb.net, dll

i added itextsharp.dll to my project. it is on my desktop. everything compiles and works fine. if i install my application on another computer it is looking for the same file itextsharp.dll on the users desktop.

how do i make it so that the DLL is built in to the project??

Comment: How do you "install the application"? If you just copy the .exe, you should also copy the .dll into the same folder. If you make an installer, then you should configure it so that it also installs the .dll - how exactly to do this depends on which installer generator you use.

Comment: yes i just copy the exe which is a setup file BUT it looks on my desktop for the DLL even though i set copy local to TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's with the Desktop now?!

1. Bundle all your deployable assemblies in the same output folder as your application's main assembly.
2. While creating the Setup...I am assuming your using MS project setup..make sure all the deployables point to a common folder target.

I don't understand your fixation with Desktop...pls let me know if that is some sort of requirement.

The only thing that is usually deployed onto Desktop is the App's Shortcut.

Comment: i guess its easier to throw stuff on the desktop. its easier to work with it that way. im not a trained computer scientist. i have a degree in finance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you add the DLL to your project, you set 'Copy Local' to true. That way, the DLL will get copied to the 'bin' folder of your application rather than the original location of the DLL.